# I am returning a table from a function, and then using that in another query on a table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, group-by, datatable

Problem Statement: I have a products table and i want to see which products match to the input product based on certain conditions
so i make a function like this:

```
-- mapper function
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION selfMapperProducts(input parameters)
    RETURNS TABLE(output parameters) 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' COST 100 VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE ROWS 1000
AS $BODY$    
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT
        DISTINCT ON (channel) channel,sku,title,brand,mrp,price,subtitle, grammage, si, units
    FROM
        products
    WHERE some_condition ORDER BY channel, ABS(price - base_price) ASC;
END;
$BODY$;
```

when i run this query this gives me:

```
select * from selfMapperProducts(input);
```

Otput format:
[image]

but when i use it like this:

```
select * from (select sku, title, selfMapperProducts(input)  products where conditon) as temp;
```

i get this:[image]

1. **my first question is how can i achieve same column wise output here?**
2. **my second question is how can i group the results by sku and title?**

desired output should look like:
[image]

Comment: You cannot group the results without specifying how you want to aggregate the other values.

Comment: then how can i take this result set from row level to column level? beacuase all other fields are same except third column @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: Perhaps you should [edit] your question and show what the desired result should look like.

Comment: just did that, thanks for the suggestion. Can you help me now?

Comment: Please do not post images, see why [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557), but instead post formatted text. See [here](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/) for generating a text table then past it in your question  between lines containing just ```